# Is it possible to have different dev VM environments and access graphics card?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualization, hypervisor

What I want to do on my laptop:

1. Develop and Run on windows with Visual Studio (CUDA, TensorRT,...)
2. Develop and Run on Linux (CUDA, TensorRT,...)
3. Environment to edit videos, photoshop,...
4. Play games
5. Environment for general use (web browser, outlook, word,...)
6. Environment to test applications
7. Possibly connecting some external GPU to offload the work (cuda,...) from my laptop's graphics card. Since I'm new to this, I haven't researched enough to understand how it can be done. But, this is in my plans.

What I did and reaserched:

- As a start, I created VM environements in my host Windows OS using VirtualBox for #1 and #2, but I cannot run inside VM, since it doesn't provide access to graphics card. Even if it did, I still need somehow to switch to a different environment when I want to play games for example.
- I probably need hypervisor type 1 if I want to have environment to play games? But, in this case I'll need a second laptop to access it, right?

Is this even possible to do on one laptop (I have strong laptop with enough RAM and SSD)

Comment: Why it's voted for "Close"? Let me know so I could rewrite my question.

Comment: I assume because this site is for questions about programming, not questions about setting up laptops.

Comment: But, it's not "setting up laptops"? The question is more how to prepare different dev environments in VM along with the ability to access graphics card.

Comment: Can I safely delete this post with an asnwer?

Answer (score 0):

Graphics cards (GPU) are PCI devices, so they can be passed to VMs with [PCI Passthrough](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF). A device is not accessible to the host during passthrough. Hot plug can be used to reattach a graphics card to a different VM or the host without rebooting.

I don't know if a Windows host supports GPU passthrough (maybe you need Windows Server), but Linux host and Windows guest seems to work.

Setting this up is easier if you have a second GPU that remains attached to the host or another computer to control the host during GPU passthrough, for example via SSH.

Comment: I don't quite I understand how I would setup my VMs so I could easily switch between the VM that's used for development (with access to graphics card) or VM that's used for gaming or VM that's used for video editor/photoshop, etc..?

Comment: The GPU needs to be attached to the VM you want to use, so the VM can use the GPU for computation and directly output its data on the screen. With a single GPU, only the visible VM can use the GPU for computation. Keyboard (and mouse) can still be relayed over the host, so you can configure a keybinding on the host that reattaches the GPU to another VM to switch between the VMs.

Comment: I'm moving my post to superuser (https://superuser.com/questions/1617143/what-hypervizor-to-use-in-my-case) since apparently this is not the right forum. Please answer there so I could continue.